# How to restrict user to use space key in Ext js form

Tags: extjs

I am new to ext js,I have created a form contains user name and password fields
.My question is how to restrict user to use spacebar,even if user tries to use spacebar
it should not take as input.

My code :

```
   Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        title:"LoginForm",
        width:"300",
        height:"200",
        items:[
                                    {
                                        xtype:"textfield",
                                        fieldLabel:"<font color='blue'><b>User Id</b></font>",
                                        allowBlank:false

                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype:"textfield",
                                        fieldLabel:"<font color='blue'><b>Password</b></font>",
                                        inputType: 'password',
                                        allowBlank:false

                                    }
                ],
        buttons:[
                                     {
                                       text:"Submit",
                                       handler:function(){

                                       }
                                      },
                                     {
                                      text:"Cancel",
                                      handler:function(){

                                      }
                                      }
                ],
        renderTo:document.body


    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi i had modified your code with some neccassary changes and it is restricting space.

```
   Ext.onReady(function(){

           Ext.apply(Ext.form.VTypes,{
            Nospace: function(v) {
                return /^[^\s]*$/i.test(v);
            },
            NospaceText: "Must not contain spaces",
            NospaceMask: /[^\s]/i
         });


        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        title:"LoginForm",
        width:"300",
        height:"200",
        items:[
                                    {
                                        xtype:"textfield",
                                        fieldLabel:"<font color='blue'><b>User Id</b></font>",
                                        allowBlank:false,
                                        vtype: 'Nospace'

                                    },
                                    {
                                        xtype:"textfield",
                                        fieldLabel:"<font color='blue'><b>Password</b></font>",
                                        inputType: 'password',
                                        allowBlank:false,
                                        vtype: 'Nospace'

                                    }
                ],
        buttons:[
                                     {
                                       text:"Submit",
                                       handler:function(){

                                       }
                                      },
                                     {
                                      text:"Cancel",
                                      handler:function(){

                                      }
                                      }
                ],
        renderTo:document.body


    });


});
```